# Sample two remaining vertices of isosceles triangle, given some constraints

Tags: python, matlab, julia, coordinates, trigonometry

Trigonometry question:

I want to find a way to randomly sample the coordinates of the two remaining vertices `C2` and `C3` of an isosceles triangle, given one initial coordinate `C1`. I have the coordinate of one vertex (`C1`), the angle between the vertex and the two remaining vertices (let's call it theta), and the distance between `C1` and the two remaining vertices `C2` and `C3` (let's call it `R`: by isosceles triangle I mean, `R` describes both the distance from `C1` to `C2` as well as from `C1` to `C3`)

How do I randomly choose two valid points `C2` and `C3` that satisfy the conditions of being `theta` degrees apart (relative to `C1`) and being the same distance `R` from `C1`?

The relationships I know are relevant here are:

```
h = R * cos(0.5 * theta) # the length of the line between C1 and the 'base' of the triangle, i.e. the line between C2 and C3

x = R * sin(0.5 * theta) # half the length of the base, i.e. the line between C2 and C3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to do it by choosing a random angle between Ox line and (c1, c2) line, let's call it alpha.

Here's Julia code

```
c1 = [0,0]
R = 5
theta = 0.3

function rotation_matrix(theta::Real)
    @. theta * [1 -1; 1 1] |> [cos sin; sin cos]
end

alpha = 2pi * rand(Float64)

c2 = R * rotation_matrix(alpha) * [1,0] + c1
c3 = R * rotation_matrix(alpha + theta) * [1,0] + c1
```

Comment: great, thanks for the code snippet! can you explain what the 'Ox line' is, though?

Comment: Ox line means Ox axis. The main idea is that it's much easier to solve this problem in terms of polar coordinate system and then transform polar coordinates into Cartesian